# Possible Create Keydown code on Button? | jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

**How to make `Paste Button == CTRL + V Keydown`?**

I have **Paste Button**

```
<button id="btn-paste">Paste Text</button>
```

I have JS [Keycodes](http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes) with command : *if CTRL + V pressed show log "I've been pressed!"*

```
$(document).keydown(function(e){
      //CTRL + V keydown combo
      if(e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 86){
            console.log("I've been pressed!");
      }
});
```

and this is **Textarea**

```
<textarea id="resultText"></textarea>
```

---

It's possible to create function with this command? :

> `Paste button` == `CTRL + V Keydown`.
>
> if `Paste button` pressed, paste text from the clipboard into textarea `#resultText`

I want to paste using Button, Paste without press CTRL + V.

**I'm not asking you to create the code,  I'm just looking for a references, because I'm not find the reference 'Paste code with button'.**